# how to replace a pattern with a string depending on part of the pattern?

Tags: awk, gawk

I have the following problem. I'm interpreting an input file, and now I'm encountering this:
I need to translate `%%BLANKx` to `x` spaces.

So, whereever in the input file, I find for example `%%BLANK8`, I need to replace `%%BLANK8` with `8` spaces, `%%BLANK10` with `10` spaces etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your String on %%BLANK tag.
After, you can read the first number present in any of your token and convert their in spaces. 
Now, you can concat every token in a new String.

Answer (score 0):

try this. I have not tested exhaustively

```
$ awk '/BLANK/{ match($0,/%%BLANK([0-9]+)/,a);s=sprintf("%"a[1]"s","") ; gsub(a[0],s)}1' file
```

Or Ruby(1.9+)

```
$ ruby -ne 'print $_.gsub(/%%BLANK(\d+)/){|m|" "*$1.to_i}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe 's/%%BLANK(\d+)/" " x $1/e' input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

using "%%BLANK" as record seperator , now if any new record that starts with a number replace the number with spaces.

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="%%BLANK";ORS=""}{MatchFound=match($0,"^[0-9]+",Matched_string);if(MatchFound){sub(Matched_string[0],"",$0);for (i=0;i<Matched_string[0];i++){$0=" "$0};print $0}else{print $0}}' InputFile.txt
```